# Can 'postsynaptic' be written as 'post-synaptic'?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Under the heading "**Excitatory and inhibitory postsynaptic potentials**" in [this article on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology/neuron-nervous-system/a/the-synapse), the word 'postsynaptic' is written with and without a hyphen. Does this imply that both ways of writing 'postsynaptic' and 'post-synaptic' are correct?

Sorry if I'm being too nitpicky here, I'm really just wondering. Maybe it has to do something with the word in front of it.

#### Edit

I completely missed the other 7 occurences of 'post-synaptic' in the article, but I still don't understand whether it means something different.

Comment: My first post on this stackexchange. I haven't looked into all the specific rules. English is not my main language, so please excuse me if I am being unclear or brkaking any rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *post-synaptic* and [*postsynaptic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postsynaptic) are grammatical. So to are *pre-synaptic* and [*presynaptic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presynaptic).

The closed version is more common that the hyphenated version. (As shown by another answer here.)

For actual context, here are two paragraphs from [the article in question](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology/neuron-nervous-system/a/the-synapse). Note that the second comes some time after the first (the emphasis exists in the referenced text):

> At the synapse, the firing of an action potential in one neuron—the presynaptic, or sending, neuron—causes the transmission of a signal to another neuron—the **postsynaptic**, or receiving, neuron—making the **postsynaptic** neuron either more or less likely to fire its own action potential.

> Chemical transmission involves release of chemical messengers known as **neurotransmitters**. Neurotransmitters carry information from the pre-synaptic—sending—neuron to the post-synaptic—receiving—cell.

I can personally see no reason for the inconsistent style decision made here. Normally, you pick one way of spelling a word and stick to it throughout—unless there is a particular context that would have it be spelled differently in a certain section.

There might be some reason that the author chose to mix the spelling of the words, but I can't determine what it could have been.

In fact, the use of the hyphenated version seems like a particularly strange choice given that the hyphenated words are used right next to em dashes, which causes a certain inability to parse the sentence quickly.

---

Comment: Yes, I agree that inconsistency *within* a single document is a bad idea or carelessness. I've added a second part to my answer to show that both are in fact used in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Everyday usage**

Here's what Google Ngram indicates. I think *postsynaptic* wins by a considerable margin. Click on the link below the picture to do your own searches.

[image]

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postsynaptic%2Cpost+synaptic%2Cpost-synaptic&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostsynaptic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20synaptic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20-%20synaptic%3B%2Cc0

**2. Scientific usage**

If you want to know what is used in the scientific literature then I suggest *Google Scholar* - Type in the various possibilities and see what the result is. For example if I search for *post-synaptic*, Google Scholar asks if I meant *postsynaptic*. I believe that this indicates that the former is less common but, as you will see, it is used somewhat in some papers.

> *Did you mean: postsynaptic*
>
> https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=post-synaptic&btnG=